Python OpenCV VideoCapture Color Differs from ffmpeg and Other Media Players
I’m working on video processing in Python and have noticed a slight color difference when using cv2.VideoCapture to read videos compared to other media players.

I then attempted to read the video frames directly using ffmpeg, and despite using the ffmpeg backend in OpenCV, there are still differences between OpenCV’s and ffmpeg’s output. The frames read by ffmpeg match those from other media players.

Below are the videos I’m using for testing:
test3.webm
test.avi
Here is my code:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import subprocess

def read_frames(path, res):
    """Read numpy arrays of video frames. Path is the file path
       and res is the resolution as a tuple."""
    args = [
        "ffmpeg",
        "-i",
        path,
        "-f",
        "image2pipe",
        "-pix_fmt",
        "rgb24",
        "-vcodec",
        "rawvideo",
        "-",
    ]

    pipe = subprocess.Popen(
        args,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
        bufsize=res[0] * res[1] * 3,
    )

    while pipe.poll() is None:
        frame = pipe.stdout.read(res[0] * res[1] * 3)
        if len(frame) > 0:
            array = np.frombuffer(frame, dtype="uint8")
            break

    pipe.stdout.close()
    pipe.wait()
    array = array.reshape((res[1], res[0], 3))
    array = cv2.cvtColor(array, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    return array

ORIGINAL_VIDEO = 'test3.webm'

array = read_frames(ORIGINAL_VIDEO, (1280, 720))

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(ORIGINAL_VIDEO, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    print(frame.shape)
    cv2.imshow("Opencv Read", frame)
    cv2.imshow("FFmpeg Direct Read", array)
    cv2.waitKeyEx()
    cv2.waitKeyEx()
    break
cap.release()

I’ve attempted to use different media players to compare cv2.VideoCapture and ffmpeg’s frame reading, to confirm that the issue lies with opencv. I’m looking to determine whether it’s a bug in OpenCV or if there are issues in my code.
EDIT:
Just use the following code to check the difference between opencv read and ffmpeg read.
cv2.imshow('test', cv2.absdiff(array, frame)*10)
cv2.waitKey(0)

Here is the result:


as I know OpenCV uses module PyQt to display window with image. Maybe you should check if it is problem with PyQt. You may also use other GUI frameworks (tkinter, PyGTK, wxPython) to display video from OpenCV. Example which uses tkinter to display streams from OpenCV - furas/python-cv2-streams-viewer

if you have frame and array then you could subtract them to see difference. Maybe problem makes color converting from RGB to BGR

OpenCV does not use PyQt by default, and in the official builds, it's not even enabled. -- this is simply a matter of opencv not being able to model color space information, so even if ffmpeg did provide this, OpenCV couldn't use it.
